# Blob patterns not working in typescript on Windows

Tags: typescript, angular-cli

Typescript is not working when using blob patterns inside tsconfig.json . Please find my tsconfig.json below .

```
 {
      "compileOnSave": false,
      "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc-e2e",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
          "../../node_modules/@types"
        ]
      },
      "files": [
        "../../test/**/*.ts"
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `files` property doesn't accept a glob pattern - it takes an array of string file names:

```
{
    ...

    "files": [
        "core.ts",
        "sys.ts",
        "types.ts"
    ]
}
```

Instead, use the `include` property - it accepts a glob as you expect:

```
{
    ... 

    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Examples taken from the "Examples" section here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html